# Help me find the datasheet of a component (547 T518A)

Tags: transistors, components, datasheet

This is a picture of a component its designator is 'Q1', so it would be a transistor, but I couldn't find it on the internet:
[image]

Comment: BC547 an NPN BJT.

Comment: I don't think that's correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick search gave me the following datasheet of the PST518A :

[Datasheet?](https://www.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/pdf/87725/MITSUMI/PST518A.html)

Comment: This looks to be it. Googling PST518A gives pictures a parts identical to the OP's picture for sale.

Answer (score 2):

This components is [PST518A](https://pdf1.alldatasheetcn.com/datasheet-pdf/view/87725/MITSUMI/PST518A.html), MFG:MITSUMI.